# BroadcastReceiver + Retrofit NetworkOnMainThreadException if app killed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, retrofit2, networkonmainthread

Logic steps are in my sample:

- App starts
- Create alarmanager with 10 secs delay

  ```
  alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000L, getIntent());

  private PendingIntent getIntent() {
      return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class), FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  }
  ```
- MyReceiver:

  ```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
       updateManager.checkUpdate()
   }
  ```
- UpdateManager:

  ```
  public void checkVersion() {
      versionManager.checkUpdate()
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
              .subscribe(versionResponse -> {
                  Log.d(TAG, "__result: " + versionResponse.getStatus());
              }, throwable -> Log.d("TAG", "_err: " + throwable.toString()));
  }
  ```

where versionManager.checkUpdate() a retforit call, return with 
a Observable.

If app is running then I'm getting result, but If i kill it before onReceive method called then I got **NetworkOnMainThreadException** exception.

```
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1513)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:117)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
    at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:40)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:185)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:149)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:84)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:214)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:213)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:41)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10700)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10700)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.subscribeInner(ObservableFlatMap.java:162)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMap$MergeObserver.onNext(ObservableFlatMap.java:139)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleToObservable$SingleToObservableObserver.onSuccess(SingleToObservable.java:59)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleMap$MapSingleObserver.onSuccess(SingleMap.java:63)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap$SingleFlatMapCallback$FlatMapSingleObserver.onSuccess(SingleFlatMap.java:111)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleJust.subscribeActual(SingleJust.java:30)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2692)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap$SingleFlatMapCallback.onSuccess(SingleFlatMap.java:84)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn$ObserveOnSingleObserver.run(SingleObserveOn.java:81)
```

Why?

Thx!

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question and post the entire stack trace associated with your exception.

Comment: OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
    OkHttp: Content-Length: 19
    {"version":"1.0.1"}
    END POST (19-byte body)
    <-- HTTP FAILED: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: That is not a stack trace. Replace `Log.d("TAG", "_err: " + throwable.toString())` with Log.e("TAG", "Exception in network I/O", throwable)`, then look in Logcat for the stack trace.

Comment: Alarms are not network. You obviously have a threading issue when a network call is happening on UI thread. I only assume that is what updateManager is. In that case you need to put it on a bg thread or the problem isn't even here.

Comment: CommonsWare - original post updated with stack trace

Comment: CmosBattery - but request happens on IO thread by.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
Otherwise when app is running then no problem, so the code can work.